# Textbox which does two things

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made textbox, but it needs to send data to other application, which have custom formatting (like `%B` is for bold, and if you want to turn off bold, you type keyword for normal font, and so).

So, formatting is much different than usual. I made textbox with buttons that can add keywords for text formatting, and that's working fine, but if I need preview in one label in same app, what is good way to do it? (I made preview button that sends text to label)

Obviously, I need to set that `%B` is starting bold text in label and so for other formatting keywords, unless there is better way?

Comment: This is hard to read and work out what you actually want help with. Best thing to do is try something that seems like it might work, then show us the code and we might be able to help improve it.

Comment: Why not just use markdown like on SO: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, are you trying to format the string from the textbox to show in the label with or without bold or are you trying to show the formatting examples like %B in the label?

for the second option I would use a literal string so that the signs don't mess you up.
ie:

```
string here = @"%Byourtextboxtext";
```

For the first option I think you need to create a function where you process the string. The function should receive a string, modify the label depending on the custom formatting, clean the string and apply it to the label.
ie:

```
        if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith(@"%B"))
        {
            char[] here = {'%', 'B'};
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            label1.Text = textBox1.Text.TrimStart(here);
        }
```

Comment: 1. Main thing is formatting by the rules of external app, example %B for bold, and that's fine, and I need to preview it in label in the way that external app would see it. So, how to make that label formats text like external app do it? Hope is more clear now.

Comment: I'll try all variants mentioned here, and see what will fit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally putting logic like this into it's own class usually makes it much easier to see where some piece of code should go. In your example I would crate a `FormattedTextModel` that holds the text. Your editable textbox can change this model, and the preview label listens to changes to this model and updates itself when needed.

The preview textbox needs to know how to format the text in *another way* so that it can be viewed, for example using a [RTF textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287595%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
class FormattedTextModel
{
    private string _raw;

    public event EventHandler TextChanged;

    public string RawText
    {
        set
        {
            _raw = value;
            EventHandler tmp = TextChanged;
            if (tmp != null) tmp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        get { return _raw; }
    }

    public string RTFText
    {
        return <Convert to rtf here>
    }
}
```

So both the editable textbox and the preview textbox has a reference to the same instance of this model. The model can be changed on keypress on the editable textbox to get a 'live' update of the preview, or triggered when using a button or such.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom ControlLable that inherited from Label or Control and then
 you must override onpaint() method of control and paint your desire text(bold,italic), something like this pseudo code:

```
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnPaint(e);//must be clear
            //tranlate your metaText for exapmle after translate:
            e.Graphics.DrawString("B", Font(Bold), Brush, Ponit);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("B", Font(Regular), Brush, Ponit+n);
        }
```

Comment: mistake:Excuse me, I think in Windows application...